# How to navigate between divs with class name on keydown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus, keydown

I have list of image divs and want to navigate between them by right,left,up and down arrows pressed on keyboard.I tried the following jQuery but the image focus never changes when i press the arrows.I want the image border glows when it receives focus so user knows which one is selected.(I want default focus to be on first div always on load of page).Could any one help me fix this problem.Thanks in advance.

Divs:

```
<div class="scroller">
<div id="Div1" style="display: visiable;">  

<div class="image1">
<a href="javascript:doIt('10')">
<img src="./content/1/102.jpg" alt="..">Movie 1
</a>
</div>
<div class="image2">
<a href="javascript:doIt('11')">
<img src="./content/2/102.jpg" alt="..">Movie 2
</a>
</div>
<div class="image3">
<a href="javascript:doIt('12')">
<img src="./content/3/102.jpg" alt="..">Movie 3
</a>
</div>
<div class="image4">
<a href="javascript:doIt('13')">
<img src="./content/4/102.jpg" alt="..">Movie 4
</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
        var index = $(":focus").index() + 1;
        if (e.which === 37) {
                alert("left:37");
            $('div a:nth-child(' + (index - 1) + ')').focus();
    } else if (e.which === 39) {
                alert("right 39");
            $('div a:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').focus();
    } else if (e.which === 38) {
                alert("Up:38");
            $('div  a:nth-child(' + (index - 1) + ')').focus();
    } else if (e.which === 40) {
                alert("Down:40");
            $('div a:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').focus();
    }
});


</script>
```

css:

```
<style>

.image {
float:left;
width: 50%;
}

img {
width:100%;
}

a:focus {
  //border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #9ecaed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}

.container {
width:100%;
}

@media (max-width: 740px){
.image {
width: 100%;
}
}

div.scroller {
overflow:scroll;    
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are the problem:

`$('div a:nth-child(' + (index - 1) + ')').focus();`

This is targeting a:nth-child of div, but since each div only ever has a single a, the logic is flawed. It should target the div as nth-child of the parent div (#Div1), like this:

`$('#Div1 div:nth-child(' + (index - 1) + ')').focus();`

You can make the divs focusable by giving them a tabindex=0 (this maintains normal tabbing order, but allows them to receive focus, making your JS logic a bit simpler).

Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVzoQK

Comment: Thanks for reply . i made the changes but still one i press any arrow the focus never changes to next one or previous one !May i know how to run the codepen ? it is not like jsfiddle:-(

Comment: Here's the same example in jsfiddle if that helps: https://jsfiddle.net/j06v8sah/2/

Comment: As you notice in the jsfiddle example onload of page the focus is not set on first thumb and when i press the arrow the focus disappears instead of focus changes to next one or previous one ! I need this feature because i am developing this so it works with remote control at the end!How to set the focus at start on first item and change it as i press different arrows ?

Comment: Well, in that case you just need to .focus() on the first div to set the default, add this line to the JavaScript:  `$(document).ready(function() { $('#Div1 div:eq(0)').focus(); });` - the focus doesn't disappear for me, it works as specified moving up or down the list, what browser are you using?

Comment: I tried it on two version of firefox(latest and older versions) but the glowing border focus didn't move on arrow right and left!

Comment: It seems Firefox and focus have some issues, I had to rework the selectors and add tabindex to the links themselves to allow them to focus, this should now work: https://jsfiddle.net/4fsyg9ay/ Note that the initial auto focus isn't working for me in jsfiddle, I'm not sure if this is because of the way it works with multiple iframes etc, but it works for me in codepen and when I paste all the code into my own local HTML page it does work, so I think that's a jsfiddle specific bug and nothing to worry about.